# Can gang members only be recruited in Los Santos?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I have never seen my own gang members outside of Los Santos (one of three major cities in the game).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can recruit any gang member **anywhere you see them**. I do believe they only stay at Los Santos but if you transport them somewhere else an dismiss them, you can re-recruit them again.

Comment: To add in Gang War mission once you survived 2 waves the area is shared between other gang and grove street family, So may find some gang members there. After owning up a territory in gang war you will be able to recruit from that area where gang war happened.

Comment: I believe the gang members can only be seen in Los Santos (one of three major cities in the game), I forgot that they move around the city. I edited my question.